# Multi-page Excel report from SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse

I need to produce a 16 page report from sales transaction data such that

```
Page1: ProductLine1
Page2: ProductLine2
.
.
Page16: ProductLine16
```

On each page the rows will represent geographical and client types, the columns will represent different statistics Like the following:

```
PageN           YTD Sales   YTD COMMISIONS  MONTH   MONTH       MONTH           MONTH           MONTH       MONTH   LAST MONTH YTD
                                            SALES   COMMISIONS  MIN COMMISION%  MAX COMMISION%  COUNT NEW   RETURNS  SALES



Location 1
Location 2,3
Location 4
Location 5,6
.
.
Location n
```

I know how to make a query to get every value, and the data will be inerted into excel through a java routine.

My question is how do such reports get done normally?

If the excel report has several hundred lines, should i make several hundred SELECT statements and join them by UNIONS ? OR Should I get the whole data in one query and depend on the adapter that will update the excel file to make the necessary groupings?

Comment: what do you mean by pages? sheets?

Comment: @Simonare its an excel template that needs to be filled, pages are group of rows with a header and footer, they are already in the file. One after the other.

Comment: You use reporting software to prepare reports, not SQL. SQL just retrieves the data for the report, it doesn't format/paginate/present it

Comment: @CaiusJard I know that. There is a java routine that will take the query output and update the excel file. The question is what to select? The whole data and group it in java or should I make a query that will produce the same number of lines as the required excel file.

Comment: In as far as there is a way *"such reports get done normally"* it is probably either through [Anton Scheffer's excellent PL/SQL extension `as_xlsx (link)(https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/) or by embedding ODBC datasources in the Excel worksheet and connecting to the database that way. You're inventing your own way of doing things so you get to choose whatever seems right to you.

Comment: I'm really not clear what your question is. We don't know what Java API you're using to generate the Excel file. Other than that, you're running some query we don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  row_number over (order by id) / <page_num> category, <other columns ... >
from whatever_table
```

would work for you.

just categorize your output and filter it inside excel file